# NodeJS CSRF Protection with Express, GraphQL and CORS enabled

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, graphql, csrf

I am creating a web service very much like shopify but using only JS. Nodejs express for an API with GraphQl and Cors enabled. VueJS for frontend. My authentication is running with JWT. But I have things like anonymous checkout so i need a CSRF protection. The thing is my API is not a router. My router is in the frontend and im only getting the data I need via Graphql through Axios calls to the API. I took a look at the csurf module and tried it out but currently the way im getting a CSRF token to the frontend is with a /getCSRFToken endpoint on the API which i've read is not a good practice and the other thing is It's enabled to access to everyone because of the CORS enabled.

This is the main source of information I have: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet

I don't know how to exactly set up the CSRF protection without having am API route for getting the CSRF token and sending it as a cookie through the response and generally make the whole thing secure with the best practices.

I was also thinking about restricting access to the API only for the domains of the shops that are in the system but don't now if that will be any good either.

Any suggestions are welcome

Answer (score 0):

You can generate the cookie client side (using `window.crypto`), then have the JS read it and send it in a header, the server simply has to verify that they match. **But** this is vulnerable to the fact the cookie is not HttpOnly (because your JS needs to read it!). For this reason, this method is not best practice, but it is better than nothing.

It also does not prevent users from issuing requests from curl and such once they figure out that they only need to provide a matching cookie and header, but they still cannot issue requests on behalf of other users unless they have the target users authorisation credentials.

---

There actually isn't anything wrong with having an API route which generates a token per request, although it does result in doubled request density (you need a new token for each request!). The reason for this is that an attacker cannot read the response from an external site (CORS will prevent this). Then you are not vulnerable to any cookie exploit, since you never store a cookie in the first place.

**Edit**: I see you hint at having CORS * enabled for this endpoint to be public. If your API really is public then you'll have probably better off using OAuth2/JWT authentication instead, this way CSRF becomes irrelevant, since the authentication does not come from cookies.

Trying to keep a value across multiple requests encounters difficulty with history functionality, so it's recommended to either use a token per request or...

You could also store a cookie from the `getCsrfToken()` request and keep it valid for some time, but make it HttpOnly, since it was issued by the API, the API will be responsible for making sure that it is receiving a valid CSRF token.

The issue with both of the above is that if you want true anonymity then you can't tie these tokens to a particular user, so one user could avoid the CSRF checks on behalf of another by using their own CSRF token!

If you can come up with some way around that whilst maintaining anonymity then the server can check the validity of the tokens that it is receiving, such that one user cannot use their token on behalf of another.

---

Your last idea (assuming that you want true anonymity) is probably the best. Provided that the user agent is trustworthy, the `referer` and `Origin` headers cannot be tampered with, so if you are happy to lock down your API to only the domains which your JS is running on, then doing a `referer`/`Origin` check server side will not be easily worked around by an attacker. This isn't best practice, but is practically effective.

Again, curl requests and such can be issued freely, but they can only be issued on behalf of another user if the attacker has the user's authorisation credentials.

---

The last thing to note is that CSRF is an alternative attack vector to XSS, but if you have XSS vulnerabilities, then CSRF defences usually become obsolete, so make sure that you defend XSS first, before implementing CSRF defence.

Comment: Im currently using JWT authentication but on login im sending it to the client site as 2 cookies. One for the signature part of the jwt which is secured and one of the payload for the clientside to read and get the user from it. Both are httpOnly and sameSite. But I don't see how this is relevant to the csrf protection since I have a anonymous checkout for which i still need csrf protection while im not authenticated. And could you please elaborate on the  OAuth2/JWT thing and how is it not using cookies? I mean how is the client side knowing im logged in ?

Comment: What I'm wondering is, is it fine if i have a route on the API /getCSRFToken to get a CSRF token for the page im about to load on the client side and if not how do i get a token to the client side

Comment: You can store tokens in local storage instead of as cookies, then send them on request. If another site tries to CSRF you, they simply don't have the tokens, and they can't get them either (where as with cookies the browser will send them), you do have to make sure that they are destroyed, invalidated or encrypted if you store them this way though.

Comment: With regard to your truly unauthenticated/anonymous endpoint, you will simply have to isolate this to your domains (option 3), unless you are prepared to craft a token which can only realistically be used by the requesting user (this is tough since presumably information like the user agent/user IP is available to the attacker as well)

Comment: About the local storage usage... I've read some articles and they say it's not a good practice using it for storing authentication information since it's not secure etc.
https://www.rdegges.com/2018/please-stop-using-local-storage/

Comment: There is little doubt that HttpOnly and SameSite Auth and CSRF Cookies are industry best practice. The issue with SameSite is that Microsoft have only just caught up and implemented it, thus any of your Users not on the latest Windows 10 using an MS browser are likely to be exploitable. I'd say the biggest issue for local storage is closure of the browser, which is why I say that if you do use it, the tokens should be both encrypted and short lived. I agree it makes them more vulnerable to XSS though, that's where HttpOnly Cookies shine.

Comment: The main issue here is that for your anonymous endpoint it's going to be difficult to offer a HttpOnly, SameSite Cookie that can't be abused without de-anonymising the checkout, if you come up with some way to do that, then that would be ideal.